# Display an option in a select based on a specific value

Tags: javascript

I need to display a specific option inside a select based on certain values of the zip code. 
So far I've managed to do the opposite, hide it based on values of the zip, but that is too easy to game.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $location = $('#ShippingOptions');
    $location.data('options', $location.find('option')); //cache the options first up when DOM loads
    $('#zip').on('change', function () { //on change event
        $location.html($location.data('options')); //populate the options
        if ($(this).val() == "12345" ) { //check for condition
            $location.find("option[value='300305']").remove(); //remove unwanted option
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "54321" ) { //check for condition
            $location.find("option[value='300305']").remove(); //remove unwanted option
        }

    });
});

</script>
<!--Zip-->
<div class="zip-field">
  <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
  <input type="number" id="zip" name="zip" />
</div>

<!--Location-->
<div class="location-field">
  <label for="location">Location</label>
  <select class="shippingDropDown" id="ShippingOptions" name="ShippingOptions"><option value="-1">Choose Shipping Option</option>
<option value="300305">Free Shipping $0.00</option></select>
</div>
```

I do no have access to add classes to the options, they are dynamically generated by a rendering engine. I can however target values which stay fixed. 
The plan was to have it hidden by default, then adding conditions in which to show it. This is not about setting a value to an option but showing/hiding an option with a certain value

A little background story: the system I work with gives me the option to add various types of shipping some free some paid. However, because there is no way to discern/filter between them, especially by zip, I am left in the hilarious position of letting the users choose either free shipping or paid shipping which, as human nature goes, it's pretty much pointless. So my idea was to have the user enter their zip and show the free option, which can only be identified by value, only to those that have a specific zip (full number) and not to anybody else. I am aware of the security issues and willing to live with them.

Is there a way to add/show that option instead of removing it?  Is there a way to set it selected?

Comment: AFAIK, just by setting the select value with `.val()` you'll get the related option shown as selected. What's wrong on going this way?

Comment: I have no idea where to go next from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="zip-list">
  <option value="26598">New York</option>
  <option value="19356">Mexico</option>
  <option value="26825">Artic Ocean</option>
  <option value="93583">A Village</option>
</select>

<p><input type="text" class="zip-filter" /></p>

var $zipList = $('.zip-list');
var $zipOptions = $('option', $zipList);
var $zipOptionsAll = $zipOptions.clone();

$('.zip-filter').on('change', function () {
    var filterText = $(this).val();
    var $filteredOptions = $zipOptionsAll.filter(function(e) {
        return $zipOptions.eq(e).val().indexOf(filterText) === 0;
    });
    if ($filteredOptions) {
        $zipList.empty().append($filteredOptions);
    } else {
        $zipList.empty().append($zipOptionsAll);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekEY4/

Should be pretty self explanatory. Note that since you are listening to the change event you have to loose focus on the text by clicking/tabbing out or pressing return before it updates.

I am also doing a "begins with" string check (indexOf) as I figure with something like postcode/zipcode you will want to show all results that begin with a certain area code before narrowing down. That means if you had "26598" and "26825" in the list and they searched for "26" both would come up.

"When the filter changes loop through and filter all the options that begin with the query. If something is found set those options, otherwise reset back to all options as nothing was found."

---

Edit:

Oh you want the inverse - easy. Simply change `indexOf(filterText) === 0` to `indexOf(filterText) !== 0`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3ZDE/

Comment: This is working in reverse. I don't need to hide all the other options except the one that corresponds, I need to hide ONLY the one that does not suit with a zip from the list.